# In PvP, how does Unstable Affliction affect the healers, strategically?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When playing in large PvP environments (rated battlegrounds, primarily), healers have the responsibility of dispelling their teammates. Warlocks have the responsibility of using [Unstable Affliction](http://wowhead.com/spell=30108) on as many players as possible. The description of Unstable Affliction states that "if the Unstable Affliction is dispelled it will cause 2007 damage to the dispeller and silence them for 4 sec."

Does this silence suffer from diminishing returns (first silence is 4 seconds, second is 2 seconds, 3 is 1 second, then immunity for 15 seconds)?

What happens when a healer's Mass Dispel dispels multiple UAs? Do those suffer from diminishing returns (e.g. a healer that dispels 4 UAs at once is immediately immune to the silence)?

How do healers deal with the silence? Can other healers dispel the silence?

*Please note that I am a DPS player that has never played a healer before, so bear with me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this silence suffer from diminishing returns

No. A player who dispels Unstable Affliction will get silenced for four seconds, every time. [Here](http://www.wowhead.com/forums&topic=190141/4-3-crowd-controls-dispels-pvp-de-buffs) you'll find a list of buffs, debuffs and their diminishing returns updated to 4.3. Notice that the silence debuff you get from Unstable Affliction is nowhere to be found.

> What happens when a healer's Mass Dispel dispels multiple UAs? Do those suffer from diminishing returns?

The healer will be affected by a single silence debuff, which does not have any diminishing returns.

> How do healers deal with the silence? Can other healers dispel the
>   silence?

There are a few ways in which a healer can deal with Unstable Affliction:

Priests have [Inner Focus](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=89485) if they chose the [Strength of Soul](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=89489/strength-of-soul) talent

Paladins have [Aura Mastery](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=31821) or [Divine Shield](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=642/divine-shield)

Shamans can use [Grounding Totem](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=8177) to catch an Unstable Affliction being casted by the warlock, if they can time it right.

Druid is the only healing class that lacks Silence prevention.

However, any player can use the [PVP Medallion](http://www.wowhead.com/item=69861) in it's various iterations, to remove the silence debuff.
Alternatively, humans may use their [Every Man For Himself](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=59752) talent to achieve the same result.

This silence effect can be dispeled by another player, too.

Comment: Priests need Strength of soul to use Inner focus as silence immunity spell afaik.

Comment: That's correct! Updating.

Comment: [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Unstable_Affliction#Patch_changes) states that the silence does suffer from diminishing returns. Are you sure that the person who wrote [that article](http://www.wowhead.com/forums&topic=190141/4-3-crowd-controls-dispels-pvp-de-buffs) didn't just forget to list UA?

Comment: I looked through all patch notes and couldn't find anything that says they deviated from that patch.  I did see forum posts stating that it didn't suffer from diminishing returns, but you can't really trust posters on the forum.  I don't see how it couldn't have DR.  I'm going to log onto my warlock when I get a chance and try to test a bit, because now I'm curious.

Comment: I play a priest, both as healer and DPS in PVP, and to my experience and understanding, it does not have DR. It behaves exactly like the fear effect an opponent suffers after dispeling my Vampiric Touch.

It would make little sense for it to have DR if you think about it. The sole purpose of the silence effect is too keep pressure on healers at all times. With DR, a healer would always opt to dispel the debuff at convenient times, so that he does not get silenced by a mage ,for example, when thing actually get hairy.

Comment: Damn Blizz and their sneaky undocumented changes.

Comment: Okay, so the UA silence does not have DR, but it can be dispelled. Does this mean that other healers are responsible for dispelling this from, say, the Mass Dispelling Priest? Since the silence has no DR, it sounds unreasonable that the affected healer would be forced to handle it alone.

Comment: Exactly. It is very important to have the other healers assigned to dispel duty on the priest who is spamming Mass Dispel.

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer, since it was based off incorrect sources.  The only thing I'd add to this, since you covered shamans, is that paladins can use Aura Mastery or Divine Shield to avoid the silence.

Comment: @Koviko does this cover all your doubts?

Comment: Yup. Your competition even turned tail and fled! Victory to @soulstriderx!

Comment: Hey now I didn't flee.  I admitted defeat, then contributed to his side, like a sir.